# Minimum functions

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,10]$ and $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0.10]$ and that they are independent.

Find the distribution function and the density function for $\min(X,Y).$

The book gives the formula for the min density function as $f_v(x)=n f_X(x)(1-F_X(x))^{n-1}$, however I have no idea what to plug in for $n.$

So far I have $f_v(x)=n \frac{1}{100}(1-\frac{x}{100})^{n-1}$ but this doesn't even help me get close to the answer in the back of the book which is $\frac{10-t}{50}.$

Can someone please help me apply this formula? Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your case n=2, because you choose minimum of 2 i.i.d  random variables.

Comment: And why you write $\frac{1}{100}$? Why $100$? You have uniform on $[0,10]$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One more thing: you need to say this is the density function for $0 < x < 10$, and that the density function is 0 otherwise.

Another method, in case it helps you: Let $V = \min(X, Y).$ Then
for $x \in (0, 1),$ we have

$$P(V > x) = P(X > x)P(Y > x) = [(10 - x)/10]^2.$$
so $F_V(x) = 1 - [(10 - x)/10]^2$ and $f_V(x) = F_V^\prime(x),$
which gives the answer in the back of the book.

Also, here is a brief simulation of 100,000 such minimums. At left, is a histogram of the results with an overlay of the density
function from the book. At right, is a plot (heavy black) of the empirical cumulative
distribution function (ECDF) with an overlay of the CDF (in green) found
above.

```
 m = 10^5
 x = runif(m, 0, 10);  y = runif(m, 0, 10)
 u = pmin(x, y)
```

[image]